# How to get details for an Ethereum transaction

Tags: transactions, etherscan

I am using [EtherScan API](https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts) for finding Ethererum Stats however I see no option to find details for a particular transaction. How can I do the same?

Comment: yes got sorted, I actually found some geth APIs as part of EtherScan only. It had that option. Your link provided could also be used.

Comment: Okay, that's cool and interesting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[EtherScan API](https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts) also provides a API for transaction details which I missed. It's part of [Geth/Parity Proxy APIs](https://etherscan.io/apis#proxy)
by name `eth_getTransactionByHash`

Comment: Are you able  to get information what ERC20 token was transferred and how many.  eth_getTransactionByHash Doesn't share token details and qty. Thanks

Comment: @Mangesh Have you found your answer ?

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the [EtherScan Transaction API](https://etherscan.io/apis#transactions) it says the version is Beta. So they may not have implemented it yet.

You may use the [EtherChain Transaction API](https://etherchain.org/documentation/api/#api-Transactions), they have it implemented to get a transaction by hash.

> **Transactions - GetTransaction**
>
> Returns a transaction by its hash.
>
> `[GET] https://etherchain.org/api/tx/:id`
>
> Parameter Field:id, Type: String, Description : The hash of the
>   transaction.

Comment: As of this moment, it seems EtherChain doesn't support APIs anymore

Comment: @khakiout Thanks for the update

Comment: This endpoint still works for some reason: https://etherchain.org/api/gasPriceOracle

Answer (score -1):

just follow this API document link https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/geth-parity-proxy#eth_gettransactionbyhash